# How to align the icons on the right to the center of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**I want to align the social media icon on the right in the center of the navigation bar along with the navigation link and logo.
I'm trying to do something like this
[navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fceSD.png)**

[Link to code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sugar-cypress-ankle)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wide div that is centered, create a div containing the icons, put it in the centerd div and then use in css `float: right;`

Comment: `code`
.social img{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.social a{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 16px;
}
.icon { display: inline-block; }

.social_center
{ display: inline-block;
  float: right;
 margin: 0 40px;
}
<div class="social_center">    
      <div class="social">
       <div class="icon ">
//code of a links
</div></div></div>
its now stacking one below other 
refer the link in above post to see the code

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that:

```
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .centered {
        width: 900px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: red;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .text {
        width: 300px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .logo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(50% + 260px);
    }
    .logo div {
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 7px;
        margin-left: 14px;
    }
</style>

<div class="header">
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="text">
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is probably aligning your content to the vertical center.
To do that set your navbar display to grid and set grid-template-column according to the structure of the content within your navbar and also place all your social icons within a div that's a direct child of the navbar.

And lastly on the div containing your social-icons, set the properties;

```css
.social_box{
   display: flex;
   justify-self: center;
   align-content: space-around;
   justify-content: center;
}
```